# Why does order of function calls impact runtime

Tags: python, performance, pytorch

I'm using pyTorch to run calculations on my GPU (RTX 3000, CUDA 11.1).  One step involves calculating the distance between one point and an array of points.  For kicks I tested 2 functions to determine which is faster as follows:

```
import datetime as dt
import functools
import timeit
import torch
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("cuda:0")

# define functions for calculating distance
def dist_geom(a, b):
    dist = (a - b)**2
    dist = dist.sum(axis=1)**0.5

    return dist

def dist_linalg(a, b):
    dist = torch.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)

    return dist

   
# create dummy data
a = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (100000, 10, 10)).astype(np.float64)
b = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1, 10)).astype(np.float64)

# send data to GPU
a = torch.from_numpy(a).to(device)
b = torch.from_numpy(b).to(device)


# test runtime of each
iterations = 1000

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_linalg, a, b))
linalg_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Linear algebra time: ", linalg_delta, " seconds per iteration")

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_geom, a, b))
geom_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Geometry time: ", geom_delta, " seconds per iteration")


print("linear algebra:geometry ratio: ", linalg_delta / geom_delta)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Linear algebra time:  0.000743145  seconds per iteration
Geometry time:  0.001446731  seconds per iteration
linear algebra:geometry ratio:  0.5136718574496572
```

So the linear algebra function is ~2x faster.  But if I call the geometry function first:

```
t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_geom, a, b))
geom_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Geometry time: ", geom_delta, " seconds per iteration")

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_linalg, a, b))
linalg_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Linear algebra time: ", linalg_delta, " seconds per iteration")      

print("linear algebra:geometry ratio: ", linalg_delta / geom_delta)
```

I get this output:

```
Geometry time:  0.001213497  seconds per iteration
Linear algebra time:  0.001136769  seconds per iteration
linear algebra:geometry ratio:  0.9367711663069623
```

The dist_geom time is nearly identical to the initial run, but the dist_linalg time is now 1.46x longer!

I've tested this multiple ways and the result is always the same: the call order seems to matter...a lot.  I think I'm missing a fundamental point here, so any help in understanding what is going on will be appreciated (and I suspect it will be so simple I'll feel foolish).

I created two sets of tensors.  The following yields the same runtime regardless of order.

```
# create 2 tensors for geometry test
a1 = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (100000, 10, 10)).astype(np.float64)
b1 = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1, 10)).astype(np.float64)

a1 = torch.from_numpy(a1).to(device)
b1 = torch.from_numpy(b1).to(device)

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_geom, a, b))
geom_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Geometry time: ", geom_delta, " seconds per iteration")

# create 2 different tensors for the linalg function
a2 = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (100000, 10, 10)).astype(np.float64)
b2 = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1, 10)).astype(np.float64)

a2 = torch.from_numpy(a2).to(device)
b2 = torch.from_numpy(b2).to(device)

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_linalg, a, b))
linalg_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Linear algebra time: ", linalg_delta, " seconds per iteration")      

print("linear algebra:geometry ratio: ", linalg_delta / geom_delta)


Geometry time:  0.0012010019999999998  seconds per iteration
Linear algebra time:  0.0007349769999999999  seconds per iteration
linear algebra:geometry ratio:  0.6119698385181707
```

That said, if I define both a1/b1 **and** a2/b2 before the function calls I see the difference in times again.  Initially I thought this was caused memory load times, but that does not really fit, right?

Comment: What if you generate `a` and `b` separately for each function run - i.e., generate them, run geom, generate again, run lin, then switch order? Does that change anything?

Comment: Also, instead of trying to do all the time calculations yourself, check out the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: @MattDMo Now *that's* interesting.  Perhaps I misunderstood your suggestion, but I genearated 2 sets of "a" and "b", separately, and swapping order no longer makes a difference.  I'll edit the question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

you just can add

```py
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

All code:

```py
import datetime as dt
import functools
import timeit
import torch
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("cuda:0")

# define functions for calculating distance
def dist_geom(a, b):
    dist = (a - b)**2
    dist = dist.sum(axis=1)**0.5

    return dist

def dist_linalg(a, b):
    dist = torch.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)

    return dist

   
# create dummy data
a = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (100000, 10, 10)).astype(np.float64)
b = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (1, 10)).astype(np.float64)

# send data to GPU
a = torch.from_numpy(a).to(device)
b = torch.from_numpy(b).to(device)


# test runtime of each
iterations = 1000

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_linalg, a, b))
linalg_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Linear algebra time: ", linalg_delta, " seconds per iteration")

torch.cuda.empty_cache()

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(dist_geom, a, b))
geom_delta = t.timeit(number=iterations) / iterations
print("Geometry time: ", geom_delta, " seconds per iteration")


print("linear algebra:geometry ratio: ", linalg_delta / geom_delta)
```

Comment: Very interesting.  This corrects the issue, though my original questions was along the lines of  "why is this happening".  Can you elaborate on *why* this fixes it?  I'm guessing the cache clearing was occuring anyway and its execution time got included in one of the other functions.  However, it doesn't make sense that this would impact only one function and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the two functions you're comparing are so fast that you end up mostly comparing the cost of torch's memory management on the GPU (since you're allocating space to do work with every call).

You can see this by reducing the number of runs.  If you reduce the number of runs to 100 instead of 1000, timeit measures significantly fewer seconds per iteration (about 10x faster on my machine).  I'm not sure if this is because cuda's memory management is getting more expensive as more allocations occur, or if it's triggering clears more often, or what.

Because of this, whichever function you time second will appear to run slower, because cuda's already done a bunch of memory management by the time that code runs.

How to fix this depends on what you want to measure.

If you expect to call these functions in a paradigm where you aren't worried about memory management overhead, then what you want to do is replace timeit with a manual loop, and on every iteration of the loop call `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` *before* timing the function call.

If you expect to call these functions in a paradigm where you *are* worried about memory management, then the solution described above of calling `torch.cuda.empty_cache` before each loop is probably the best one, because it will accurately measure if one of them has higher memory management overhead.  In this case I would make sure to make the number of runs large enough that you're measuring the steady-state cost of the memory management, since that's probably what you'll be worried about later.

Alternatively, I would just not worry about it much; any function that runs so quickly it's being dominated by memory management overhead usually isn't worth optimizing.

Comment: That almost makes sense.  If you re-read the original post you will see that the only function's runtime that was impacted by changing the call order was the dist_linalg function.  Maybe the linear algebra has more memory issues...don't know.  Regardless, it's pretty consistent that the linear algebra solution is faster, which is what I expected.

Comment: The geometry runtime went from 0.001446731 to 0.001213497 when you switched to running it first.  I pretty strongly suspect that's real and not random noise, because I saw a similar shrinkage across multiple runs, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I wonder about that time difference too.  The difference is the linalg function was huge, so I initially assumed the difference in the geometry function was noise.  Also, I've seen a lot of variability in the run times...which makes me wonder how to *really* compare the speed of the two functions.  I expect better consistency from CPUs, I'm not sure about GPUs though.  That said, my gut tells me that the variability I see might be caused by memory operations.  Just not sure how to prove this (not that it's *that* important at this point).